# Take one variable from arrayList and add it to new arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a dog class with name, breed, age and weight.
I also have an arraylist which contains objects with these four attributes. Now I want to create an auction(which also have an own class) and I want to get the name from the dogArraylist and add it to a new Arraylist of auctions.
How can I do this? Is it possible?

```
private void newAuction(ArrayList<AuctionHouse> auctionHouse) {
    boolean foundIt = false;

    System.out.println("Enter the name of the dog> ");
    String nameOfDog = input.nextLine();
    for(int i = 0; i < dog.size(); i++) {
        if(dog.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameOfDog)) {
            foundIt = true;

            if(foundIt) {
                auctionHouse.add(i);

            }
        }
    }
    if(!foundIt) {
        System.out.println("Error: no such dog ");
    }
}
```

AuctionHouse class:

```
public class AuctionHouse {
    private String auctionDog;

    public AuctionHouse(String auctionDog) {
        this.auctionDog = auctionDog;
    }   

    public String getAuctionDog() {
        return auctionDog;
    }

    public void setAuctionDog(String name) {
        this.auctionDog = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s", auctionDog);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with your code?

Comment: It doesnt allow me to add the name/object from the dogArrayList to the new ArrayList auctionHouse

In my class AuctionHouse I only have the String name unlike the Class Dog which have String, String, int, int.. But I only want the name from the object and not the rest

Comment: share the `AuctionHouse` class please

Comment: **Side Note:** Your `if (foundIt)` will always be `true` because you set it to true on the previous line...

Comment: Add the code to your question, not a comment. You can [edit] your question directly. Also, please read the [ask] guide and provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: no, it only gets true if the name of the dog matches the input from user, And only then is it true

Answer (score 0):

Use enhanced for-loop instead and note: `foundIt` variable and `if(foundIt)` is redundant. Also `newAuction()` method should *probably* takes a list of dog as a parameter and return new list of auction. I guess it is more logical. Try:

```
private List<AuctionHouse> newAuction(List<Dog> dogs) {
    List<AuctionHouse> auctionHouse = new ArrayList<>();
    String nameOfDog = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    for (Dog d : dogs) {
        if (d.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameOfDog)) {
            auctionHouse.add(new AuctionHouse(d.getName()));
        }
    }

    if (auctionHouse.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("not found");
    }
    return auctionHouse;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked wonders!! just the d.getName() instead but everything else worked fine! ;)

But does this work if I want to add more dogs to the arraylist? doesnt it create a new list every time?

Comment: @Markus Glad to help!